# How do I check which Redmine version I'm running?

Tags: redmine

Does someone know where/how to check which Redmine version I'm running?

Comment: Please read the FAQ, SU is not about web services.

Comment: @Molly, this is kind of a gray area... the user is most likely running this on their own computer, and therefore it does fit into the realm of SU, or maybe SF.

Comment: I do agree with @heavyd and really don't understand people that 'have to' close questions. If you 'don't like them' leave them somebody else might attend them.

Comment: I didn't know Redmine was a web service. Lol.

Comment: Redmine is an application. I don't understand why this kind of question gets closed.

Comment: If you consider that you are using Redmine in your working computer, it can be considered as a software, not network service!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The change-log can be found at:

```
$INSTALL_DIR/doc/CHANGELOG
```

The first entry in the change-log gives the version number.
The way to go is to login as admin, then check the administration link and then info.

Comment: you can also enter this url `http://YOUR-SERVER-NAME/admin/info`. As explained at [redmine.org](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/10395)

Comment: what if you do not have admin access?